# How to open a file with the system default application for a different file type in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I want to open a specific file from C# with the Windows default application. This is the code I came up with:

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("awesometool.settings");
```

The problem is that Windows has no default application set for ".settings"-files. Thus the file does not open and an exception is thrown.

But I know that the file is actually in JSON format. And for that a default handler is registered. Is there any way I can open the file using the default handler for .json instead of .settings?

PS: the file name is fixed for me. I cannot simply rename it to .json.